# MPI. Maximum number of communicators and processes

Tags: mpi

I would like to ask two questions:

What is maximal number of communicators in MPI? What is maximal number of processes in MPI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very likely implementation dependent.
the standard states a rank is an int, and in Fortran (before Fortran 2008 bindings) a communicator is a Fortran integer (which might not have the same size than a C integer)
bottom line, i think there is a hard limit of 2 billion MPI tasks in MPI_COMM_WORLD, and there is likely a similar hard limit of 2 billion communicators.
once again, a given implementation might have lower limits.

Comment: There are also limits of process number in networking hardware (hard to create queues for any-to-any process communication). Practical limits are around 1 million processes at 2009: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.148.7674&rep=rep1&type=pdf "MPI on a Million Processors" by P Balaji - doi>10.1007/978-3-642-03770-2_9

Comment: The handle types in Fortran 2008 bindings are nothing more than record type wrappers around the integer handles, so not much changes there.

Comment: @osgx Thank you for the link to that interesting paper —what date was this paper published?

Comment: @HristoIliev my point was that even if Fortran `INTEGER` are 64 bits, you are likely constrained by (32 bits) C `int`

Comment: My point was that the first statement in brackets gives the impression that something has changed in the Fortran 2008 bindings, but it really hasn't, except that the integer handles are "boxed" in their own record types.

Comment: I thought `type(MPI_Comm)` was a truly opaque type, but I stand corrected: the MPI standard specifies this is (oversimplified) an `INTEGER`. Thanks for the insight!